# Mystery issue with GIF upload?

Tags: gd, gif

Alright, so whenever I upload this GIF to my board (NGINX+PHP-FPM) I get a slow down until an eventual 504 Gateway Time-out, alright, so I know what you're thinking, "go ahead and fix those nginx.conf and php-fpm settings", well I tweaked them to near perfection last night, my server is running brilliantly now. However, that one particular GIF still screws up, runs php-FPM to almost 100% (I have a great top of the line quad core processor in my server, my server is by no means primitive).

So want to know where it gets weirder? I've uploaded 10MB GIF's with bigger dimensions than the one in case (the one which is causing the issues is about 600KB) and had the server process them ridiculously quickly.

Alright! So let's get into the log, error_log doesn't output anything in regards to this issue. So I went ahlead and set up a slowlog within the php-FPM config.

Here's the issue:
   `[02-Oct-2011 05:54:17]  [pool www] pid 76004
    script_filename = /usr/local/www/mydomain/post.php
    [0x0000000805afc6d8] imagefill() /usr/local/www/mydomain/inc/post.php:159
    [0x0000000805afb908] fastImageCopyResampled() /usr/local/www/mydomain/inc/post.php:107
    [0x0000000805af4240] createThumbnail() /usr/local/www/mydomain/classes/upload.php:182
    [0x0000000805aeb058] HandleUpload() /usr/local/www/mydomain/post.php:235`

Okay, let's look at post.php (line 159 in bold):
               `if (preg_match("/png/", $system[0]) || preg_match("/gif/", $system[0])) {
        $colorcount = imagecolorstotal($src_image);
        if ($colorcount <= 256 && $colorcount != 0) {
            imagetruecolortopalette($dst_image,true,$colorcount);
            imagepalettecopy($dst_image,$src_image);
            $transparentcolor = imagecolortransparent($src_image);
            **imagefill($dst_image,0,0,$transparentcolor);**
            imagecolortransparent($dst_image,$transparentcolor);
        }`

Line 107:
    `fastImageCopyResampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, $old_x, $old_y, $system);`

upload.php, line 182 (in bold):
    `**if (!createThumbnail($this->file_location, $this->file_thumb_location, KU_REPLYTHUMBWIDTH, KU_REPLYTHUMBHEIGHT))** {                                         exitWithErrorPage(_gettext('Could not create thumbnail.'));`

(note, that error does not show up)

The other post.php (line 235):
    `$upload_class->HandleUpload();`

So what can I do? How can I fix this? I know this is a tough issue, but if you guys could give me any input, it would be greatly appreciated.

Oh and in case anyone is curious, here's the GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwrMb.gif

Comment: I just found some info in the error_log:
2011/10/02 13:44:33 [warn] 76825#0: *250 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/tmp/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000008, client: MY.IP.., server: .org, request: "POST /post.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.", referrer: "http://www."
2011/10/02 13:45:59 [error] 76825#0: *250 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: MY.IP.AD.., server: .org, request: "POST /post.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php.sock:", host: "www.", referrer: "http://www."

Comment: Hello, Did you solve this? Please share with others

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `client_body_buffer_size` directive in your nginx configs?

See more here: http://www.lifelinux.com/how-to-optimize-nginx-for-maximum-performance/