# GD+PHP: Exception to see if imagefail fails?

Tags: gd

```
imagetruecolortopalette($dst_image,true,$colorcount);
imagepalettecopy($dst_image,$src_image);
$transparentcolor = imagecolortransparent($src_image);
imagefill($dst_image,0,0,$transparentcolor);
imagecolortransparent($dst_image,$transparentcolor);
```

So I want something like:
if imagefill fails
unlink
exit with error
else
continue with imagefill

Or:
if imagefill takes more than X seconds
unlink
exit with error
else
continue with imagefill

Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: Why would `imagefill` ever fail if `$dst_image` is a valid image resource? Can you add a bit more information about your specific situation?

Comment: Hey Pekka, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626580/mystery-issue-with-gif-upload

Comment: Hmm. 

There is no way to "timeout" a PHP function, at least not directly. I guess it has to do with the complexity of the images that imagefill() is processing. This is tough...

Comment: Hey Pekka, the weird thing is that I can upload more complex images than that, larger, bigger dimensions, even GIF's with transperancies with alot of ease. imagefill is obviously incapable of working on some images so I'd like to throw an exception if it ever comes up again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching over to imagemagick.

-Two times faster.
-Uses less memory.
-No more errors.